# remove body content of index.html using gulp

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp, gulp-rename

I can able to rename file name from index. using following configuration

Gulp.js

```
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.task('modify-html', function () {
  gulp.src('reports/index.html')
    .pipe(rename('/app.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('reports/'));
});
```

Does anyone know how to delete the body content of my html file using gulp

index.html

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gulp-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace) it replaces the HTML block.

Mark the content which needs to be removed

```
<!-- build:remove -->
Put all the content which needs to be removed, in the block
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and use it like

```
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace')
gulp.task('modify-html', function () {
  gulp.src('reports/index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({ remove : '' }))
    .pipe(rename('/app.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('reports/'));
});
```

---

Then, You can use [gulp-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dom)

```
var dom = require('gulp-dom');
gulp.task('modify-html', function () {
    gulp.src('reports/index.html')
    .pipe(dom(function () {
            this.querySelector('body').innerHTML = '';
            return this;
        }))
    .pipe(rename('/app.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('reports/'));
});
```

Note: I have not tested it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to remove the body content using script itself, For the above one i have to add manually some extra code which necessary to remove body content from html

Comment: ,awesome work, thank you very much,  its working fine right now

Answer (score 0):

Use `gulp-string-replace`

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');

gulp.task('clearBody', function (done) {
        
    gulp.src('file.html')
    .pipe(replace(new RegExp('<body>(.*?)<\/body>', 'm'), '<body><\/body>'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('newFile.html'));
           
    done();
});
```